# Another riddle for scientists

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I have one start
and usually many endings.
I'm very smart
when guiding you to sorted findings.

For you I offer
many useful suggestions
but I only answer
to "yes-no" questions.

(The title gives you a hint, by the way)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I love computer programming (particular algorithms and **data structures**). So my answer would be

> [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (Binary Search Tree)

Here is an image for the same

> [image: A binary search tree]

I have one start

> Root node

and usually many endings.

> Leaf nodes

I'm very smart
when guiding you to sorted findings.

> BST smartly guides your way in nodes arranged in a sorted fashion.

For you I offer
many useful suggestions
but I only answer
to "yes-no" questions.

> BST can be used to fetch a sorted list, find whether an item is present, find the closest item etc, but at each node all that you can decide is whether you should go left or right (yes-no)

About the title hint:

> Scientists here means computer scientists

Answer (score 2):

> A tree based sorting algorithm, that starts with 2 random picks.
> The one start is the mess that needs to be sorted. He guides us to a sorted list, which is useful. However, every time you run it, it is constructed a little differently, due to the random factor. It only answers to yes/no questions in the sense of checks with bools (is greater than, ...) The only problem is that it could work with any sort of unsorted list.
> Except of course, it sorts only ints for example, so in that sense it has only "one" start (a list filled with ints)

Just read the previous answer. Looks like my answer isn't as original as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

> I think this may be a classification system, for example- guiding you to sorted findings. You can only answer a classification system by saying yes or no. And the end is one of very many. So that is my guess, a classification system.

Answer (score 0):

I have one start

**BORN IN LIFE**
and usually many endings.
**DESTINATION OF CARRIER**
I'm very smart
when guiding you to sorted findings.
**THINKING OF THE LIFE**
For you I offer
many useful suggestions
**THOUGHT OF THE LIFE**
but I only answer
to "yes-no" questions.
**DECISION MAKING MIND**

(The title gives you a hint, by the way)
**LIFE PURPOSE**